# ¿Cómo evitar escribir más de una letra V en grupo de celdas A1:A10 y no se trasponga hacia C1:C10 el dato del celdas B1:B10?

Tags: excel

Presento este problema: Tengo un grupo de celdas en una columna dada, por ejemplo desde la A1:A7, y en las que solamente en una de ellas (celdas), debo escribir la letra V. Con lo cual entonces me trasponga el dato correspondiente, que esté en la misma fila pero en un grupo de celdas de una columna diferente, por ejemplo desde B1:B7, y pues me escriba ese dato en la respectiva celda de esa misma fila pero en otra columna, por ejemplo C1:C7

Hasta ahora tengo la siguiente formulación en Excel, para las celdas C1:C7 de la Tabla 1 con circulo azul.

```
              =SI(((A1:A7)="V");B1:B7;"")
```

El asunto problema es que **no deseo que por error** se escriba otra V (Ver Tabla 2 con circulo naranja), en otra celda del conjunto A1:A7. En mi caso de la formula arriba concebida, resulta que ello no se impide, y pues permite escribir otra V, en otra cualquiera celda de esa columna (Ver Tabla 2 con circulo naranja), y entonces se copia el valor del dato que esta contenido en la fila del conjunto B1:B7 en la respectiva celda de la fila del conjunto C1:C7. Véase la Tabla 2 con circulo naranja. Eso es lo que deseo solventar!

Agradezco una ayuda, por favor!
[image: Tabla excel victor]

Comment: Hola. No entiendo la pregunta. ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo con datos reales?

Comment: Esei, gracias por tu tiempo, vale! Espero que con esta nueva edición a la pregunta sobre mi asunto entonces tu me puedas facilitar una agradecida solución. Buenas tardes tengas!

Answer (score 3):

Ahora entiendo lo que dices. Lo que quieres es limitar la cantidad de V que pueden aparecer en esas cedas. Lo puedes hacer con la opción **Validación de datos** basado en una fórmula:

> [Aplicar la validación de datos a
> celdas](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/aplicar-la-validaci%C3%B3n-de-datos-a-celdas-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249)

En tu caso, quieres una fórmula que cuente el número de veces que aparece la letra V. Si esa cuenta es mayor a 1, entonces que no deje poner más V.

Si tus datos están en el rango `A1:A7`, pues tu fórmula sería:

`CONTAR.SI($A$1:$A$7;"V")<=1`

> [Función
> CONTAR.SI](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/funci%C3%B3n-contar-si-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)

Y la aplicamos en validación de datos, dentro de la pestaña datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchissssimas gracias, chamo! Pude hacer eso que me sugeriste o propusiste, y así resolví el problema planteado! Mi gran saludo para ti!